# in As3, if you don't declare function as neither public or private in class what does it become then

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

If in inside package>class... i declare and define a function that is without starting public/private part. Where would it be accessible and how is it different from private functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default visibility level is `internal` which means the members are accessible from within the same package. This is explained in the [Class property attributes](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f32.html) section in the ActionScript 3 manual. [Class definitions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f33.html) itself without a visibility specification are also `internal`.